# zpool reporting same drive as active and spare

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, ubuntu-16.04

I rebooted my Ubuntu 16.04.03 system and my **systemd** startup jobs aren't well organized yet because it does not bring up ZFS. (that's a different topic)  So I did a `zpool import sbn` and ended up with the following status:

```
# zpool status
  pool: sbn
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 20h49m with 0 errors on Sun Feb 11 21:13:58 2018
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    sbn         ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz2-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sde     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdf     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdg     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdh     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdi     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdj     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdk     ONLINE       0     0     0
    spares
      sdk       FAULTED   corrupted data

errors: No known data errors
```

The array is working fine but I would like to fix the FAULTED drive message and add back in the spares (**sdl** and **sdm**).   I am not sure how **sdk** got listed as a spare while also being active but how do I remove it from the spare list without removing from the raidz2-0?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should not create zpools with `sd*` device names. These may appear in a different order each time you reboot the machine. And this may cause drives to get "lost". Instead, use the unique names which appear under `/dev/disk/by-id` which do not change.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes I understand that but that tip was in one of the tutorials that I followed when I first set up this system.  I didn't want tot try to change that in a production system.

Comment: Hmm. There is probably a way to fix that but I don't know it offhand.

Comment: To reimport the pool with the correct device names, do the following: 1) export it; 2) delete the `/etc/zfs/zpool.cache` file; 3) execute `zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-uuid sbn`; 4) check the result with `zpool status`